# Custom GeoPoint object in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using spring boot 2.3.4.

Is there a way to use a custom GeoPoint object instead of org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint ?

If so, how could the mapping be overridden ? putMapping is deprecated.

```
@Document(indexName="myIndex")
public class MyDocument{
    @GeoPointField
    private MyPositionDocument position;
    // currently this only works with
    // private GeoPoint position;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the first part, annotating the property with `@GeoPointField`. This ensures that the correct index mappings will be written so that the type of `position` will be `geo_point`.

The next thing is that you will need to create custom converters to convert from a `MyPositionDocument` to a type that is supported by Elasticsearch (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html#geo-point) and one converter for the other direction.

As for registering custom converters, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.conversions